# construct concept in Php unclear

Tags: php, oop

Why the construct of the class Cars is being called as I have not created object for the class Cars?

```
<?php 


class Cars{

function __construct(){

echo "i am cars";

}

}


class SmallCars extends Cars{


}

$car = new SmallCars();

 ?>
```

Comment: its because of inheritance in object programming, your SmallCars get all the Cars functions

Comment: That's the very definition of OO. If you don't override, super class will help you.

Answer (score 3):

When you extend a class, the child will inherit the parent's constructor unless you explicitly tells it not to

From the documentation:

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private).

Also HReynaud has pointed this out in the comment section.

This question has been covered before in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477224/php-extended-construct)

PHP __construct() documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)